# Edit / hide Nginx Server header under Alpine Linux

Tags: docker, nginx, alpine-linux

When I use `curl --head` to test my website, it returns the server information.

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/nginx/how-to-remove-the-server-header-in-nginx) to hide the nginx server header.
But when I run the command `yum install nginx-module-security-headers`
, it returns `yum: not found`.

I also tried `apk add nginx-module-security-headers`, and it shows that the package is missing.

I have used `nginx:1.17.6-alpine` as my base docker image. Does anyone know how to hide the server from header under this Alpine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the alternate solution. The reason that it shows binary not compatible is because I have one nginx pre-installed under the target route, and it is not compatible with the header-more module I am using. That means I cannot simply install the third party library from Alpine package.

So I prepare a clean Alpine OS, and follow the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/openresty/headers-more-nginx-module#installation) to build Nginx from the source with additional feature. The path of build result is the prefix path you specified.

Answer (score 10):

I think I have an easier solution here: https://gist.github.com/hermanbanken/96f0ff298c162a522ddbba44cad31081. Big thanks to hermanbanken on Github for sharing this gist.

The idea is to create a multi stage build with the nginx alpine image to be a base for compiling the module. This turns into the following `Dockerfile`:

```
ARG VERSION=alpine
FROM nginx:${VERSION} as builder

ENV MORE_HEADERS_VERSION=0.33
ENV MORE_HEADERS_GITREPO=openresty/headers-more-nginx-module

# Download sources
RUN wget "http://nginx.org/download/nginx-${NGINX_VERSION}.tar.gz" -O nginx.tar.gz && \
    wget "https://github.com/${MORE_HEADERS_GITREPO}/archive/v${MORE_HEADERS_VERSION}.tar.gz" -O extra_module.tar.gz

# For latest build deps, see https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/master/mainline/alpine/Dockerfile
RUN  apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
    gcc \
    libc-dev \
    make \
    openssl-dev \
    pcre-dev \
    zlib-dev \
    linux-headers \
    libxslt-dev \
    gd-dev \
    geoip-dev \
    perl-dev \
    libedit-dev \
    mercurial \
    bash \
    alpine-sdk \
    findutils

SHELL ["/bin/ash", "-eo", "pipefail", "-c"]

RUN rm -rf /usr/src/nginx /usr/src/extra_module && mkdir -p /usr/src/nginx /usr/src/extra_module && \
    tar -zxC /usr/src/nginx -f nginx.tar.gz && \
    tar -xzC /usr/src/extra_module -f extra_module.tar.gz

WORKDIR /usr/src/nginx/nginx-${NGINX_VERSION}

# Reuse same cli arguments as the nginx:alpine image used to build
RUN CONFARGS=$(nginx -V 2>&1 | sed -n -e 's/^.*arguments: //p') && \
    sh -c "./configure --with-compat $CONFARGS --add-dynamic-module=/usr/src/extra_module/*" && make modules


# Production container starts here
FROM nginx:${VERSION}

COPY --from=builder /usr/src/nginx/nginx-${NGINX_VERSION}/objs/*_module.so /etc/nginx/modules/

.... skipped inserting config files and stuff ...

# Validate the config
RUN nginx -t
```

Comment: I saw a comment on one of the related issues that compiling other modules on the official image is now supported see: https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/tree/master/modules

Answer (score 4):

Alpine repo probably doesn't have the `ngx_security_headers` module but, the mentioned tutorial also provides an option of using `Headers More` module. You should be able to install this module in your alpine distro using the command:

```
apk add nginx-mod-http-headers-more
```

Hope it helps.

[Source](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=nginx-mod*header*&branch=edge)

Comment: Now I faced another problem. ```nginx: [emerg] module "/etc/nginx/modules/ngx_http_headers_more_filter_module.so" is not binary compatible in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:5```

Comment: @wuchi : The ".so" file is present in `/usr/lib/nginx/modules/ngx_http_headers_more_filter_module.so` and not in `/etc/nginx/modules/ngx_http_headers_more_filter_module.so` as the error says. Can you try to find why it is pointing to the wrong directory?

Comment: I check both ```/usr/lib/nginx/modules``` and  ```/etc/nginx/modules```, and they all have ```ngx_http_headers_more_filter_module.so```. 

I load the file by ```load_module modules/ngx_http_headers_more_filter_module.so;```. Is this command causes pointing to wrong directory?

Comment: @wuchi : I'm not sure. I've never worked with nginx.

Comment: You installed nginx from the offical repositories. You need to add NGINX's mainline or stable locations and their key. Then uninstall everything and reinstall nginx. To build modules you will need to download the correct nginx version files and compile a dynamic module from that nginx version source folder, it will generate the module in ./objs folder, copy that .so file to the relevant directory.